# Method inside Action Callback firing but not navigating to view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am using Prism and I have a Status Module with the following ViewModel:

```
public class StatusViewModel : WorkSpaceViewModel, IStatusQueryViewModel
{
    private bool _isActive;
    private StatusContext _context;        

    public StatusViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<StatusEvent>()
            .Subscribe(x => UpdateStatus(x), ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
        IsActive = false;
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isActive, value); }
    }

    public StatusContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _context, value); }
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(StatusContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            Context = context;
            IsActive = true;

            if (Context.Callback != null)
            {
                 Timer t = new Timer(x =>
                {
                    Context.Callback.Invoke();
                    IsActive = false;
                }, null, 3000, 0);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I fire the status like:

```
_statusQuery.SetStatus(new StatusContext(string.Format("Cargando datos del servidor {0}", server.NombreInstancia),StatusType.Informative,
                    () =>
                    {
                        var targetUri = new Uri("SqlMasterView", UriKind.Relative);
                        var navParameters = new NavigationParameters();
                        navParameters.Add("selectedServer", server);
                        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ServerInfoBarRegion, targetUri, navParameters);
                    }));
```

The code is being run after the callback.invoke in StatusViewModel but nothing happens, not view poping up, in the the debuger it reads:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Prism.Wpf.dll
```

By the way, dont know if it matters but the statusQuery is wrapped inside another callback:

```
_dialogQuery.Publish(
            new DialogContext(DialogType.Prompt, 
                String.Format("Desea cargar los datos del servidor {0}?", server.NombreInstancia), null, x =>
        {
            bool b = x == DialogResult.Ok;
            if (b)
            {
                _statusQuery.SetStatus(new StatusContext(string.Format("Cargando datos del servidor {0}", server.NombreInstancia),StatusType.Informative,
                    () =>
                    {
                        var targetUri = new Uri("SqlMasterView", UriKind.Relative);
                        var navParameters = new NavigationParameters();
                        navParameters.Add("selectedServer", server);
                        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ServerInfoBarRegion, targetUri, navParameters);
                    }));
            }
        }));
```

Maybe it has something to do with threads? Thank you

**EDIT:** Before using the statusQuery the code was working fine

**EDIT 2:** I tryed with System.Timers.Timer and First Chance exceptions being throw anyway

Answer (score 0):

Okay if anyone arrives here with the same problem, Dispatcher solved it:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal),
                (Action)(() =>
                {
                    Context.Callback.Invoke();
                    IsActive = false;
                    Dispose();
                }
            ));
```